# How can i get Ubuntu OS on a macintosh computer?

Tags: 12.04, mac

Please i'm currently looking for a solution to install linux ubuntu on my imac. Is someone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac)

Helpful links:

[Ubuntu on iMac](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111017)

[Issues?](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-imac-or-will-it-cause-issues/)

[EFI-booting ubuntu on mac](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html)